# Angularjs if/else statements

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements

```
<div class="company_name" ng-controller="CompanyName">
 <h1 class="left">
     {{data.company_name}}
 </h1>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is make it so that if data.company_name hasn't been added through an input field, it shows a placeholder "Company name", how can that be done using angularjs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf) and do something like

```
<div class="company_name" ng-controller="CompanyName">
 <h1 class="left">
     <span ng-if="data.company_name === ''">
       // Some placeholder
     </span>
     <span ng-if="data.company_name !== ''">
       {{data.company_name}}
     </span>
 </h1>
</div>
```

BTW ngIf is a new directive added in v1.1.5 so you might need to upgrade your angular version

See my plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/qiN2XshEpay6e6zzhUKP

Comment: That doesn't really work, the placeholder is still there and doesn't disappear when I start typing.

Comment: I added a Plunker to my answer for you to be able to test

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep the code clean is to use a filter. This piece of code adds a class to an active tab.

```
var filters = angular.module('filters');
filters.filter('ie', function(){
  return function(v, yes, no){
      return v ? yes : no;
  };
});
```

Template

```
<li class="{{activeTab == 'home' | ie: 'active-class':''}}">
    Home
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Using `ng-if`, `ng-else-if`, and `ng-else` in your project use this:

https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-elif

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) condition for the check company name vlaue. Let's take example of

```
 <span ng-if="driver.status_flag == 1">
    <i ngif="{{driver.status_flag}}" class="icon-ok-sign icon-2x link" style="color:#090" href="#" title="Payment received" ></i>
 </span>
```

In above example I have added condition status_flag value is 1 then the inside span value will show. Same way with your case you can add statement like

```
<span ng-if="data.company_name === ''">
        <i ngif="{{driver.status_flag}}" class="icon-ok-sign icon-2x link" style="color:#090" href="#" title="Payment received" ></i>
     </span>
```